# How do we get $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$ from $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\mathbf{B}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics

I have Maxwell's equations as follows:

$$\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\mathbf{B} \ \ \ \ \text{Faraday's law}$$
$$\nabla \times \mathbf{H} = \mathbf{J} + \dfrac{\partial{\mathbf{D}}}{\partial{t}} \ \ \ \ \text{Ampére's law}$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{D} = \rho \ \ \ \ \text{Gauss's law}$$
$$\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0 \ \ \ \ \text{Gauss's law}$$
where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field (V/m), $\mathbf{H}$ is the magnetic field (A/m), $\mathbf{D}$ is the electric displacement flux density (C/m$^2$), and $\mathbf{B}$ is the magnetic flux density (Vs/m$^2$ or Webers/m$^2$).

I am told that Gauss's law $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$ is derivable from Faraday's law $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\mathbf{B}$ by taking the divergence and noting that $\nabla \cdot ( \nabla \times \mathbf{E}) = 0$ for any vector $\mathbf{E}$. Why/how is $\nabla \cdot ( \nabla \times \mathbf{E}) = 0$, and how do we then get $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{B} = 0$ from $\nabla \times \mathbf{E} = - \dfrac{\partial}{\partial{t}}\mathbf{B}$?

Comment: No way. The other equations only say anything about $\partial\mathbf{B}/\partial t$. So if we replace $\mathbf{B}$ with a vector field $\mathbf{B}'=\mathbf{B}+\mathbf{X}$, where $\mathbf{X}$ is any vector field satisfying $\partial \mathbf{X}/\partial t=\mathbf{0}$, then only the last equation is affected, and hence cannot be a consequence of the rest of them.

Comment: These equations are independent therefore such derivation is not possible (otherwise they would not be stated separately in the set of Maxwell's equations).

Comment: Interesting. Thank you both for the feedback.

Comment: You could in special cases such that when you assume ${\bf B}=e^{i\omega t}\bf {B_0(r)}$.

Comment: This seems to be an error by the author, or there are hidden assumptions. I have made another question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681628/141502 for the physicists to review.

Comment: Ok, it seems that we solved the confusion here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/681628/141502 (see Cyrus Tirband's answer).